# Cookies after NGINX reverse proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, cookies, reverse-proxy

Rails 5.1 application.

My **main_domain.com** is blocked by ad blockers, so users cannot use direct links to pictures from my website.
I decided to use **new_domain.com** + NGINX reverse proxy to redirect requests from **new_domain.com** to **main_domain.com** and it works. NGINX config:

```
server {
  server_name new_domain.com;

  location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Connecting-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_pass https://main_domain.com;
  }
}
```

But there is a new problem: cookies on **main_domain.com** after reverse proxy are missing.

The strange thing is that after proxy there is correct domain inside request and cookies:

```
pry(main)> request.domain
=> main_domain.com
pry(main)> cookies.request.domain
=> main_domain.com
```

but needed key `uniq_key` is empty:

```
pry(main)> cookies[:uniq_key]
=> nil
```

although it is was created before and is visible in a browser dev console if I open **main_domain.com**.

Why cookies are empty and how can I read them? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably not the most secure of methods but why not add the cookies to the URL you're proxying to, and then reassign the cookies based on the params?

Comment: @Mark I can't read cookies from `main_domain.com` before proxying, because I have URL of type `https://new_domain.com/image.jpg` which is proxied to `https://main_domain.com/image.jpg` and only then I expect to read `cookies[:uniq_key]` inside the application.

Answer (score 3):

(1) There is difference between **redirection** and **proxying**. The former is when a server issues a special HTTP status along with a new resource location and a browser makes a new request to the new location. So the browser here makes two requests. The latter is when your server *forwards* a request to another server. And from the browser's point of view it appears as if the original server returns the response.

So, according to your source code fragment, you are doing **proxying**.

(2) Cookies belong to domains. When a browser makes a request to **new_domain.com**, it will not send cookies that were set by **main_domain.com**, because the browser makes only one request to `new_comain.com`, because you are doing **proxying**, not **redirect**.

---

I think I answered your question "why". I do not know "how to fix", because something is seriously off with your approach and I have no idea what tradeoffs are possible or what changes are affordable.